# How do I generate a TOML file with placeholder lines showing all missing values using Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I want the Serde serializer to write empty values to the TOML output. The result is a configuration file so it would be great if I could include empty keys so the user sees that the option is available.

```
struct X {
    attr: Option<String>,
}
```

should yield

```
attr = "value"
```

or something like this

```
# attr =
```

It does not have to be a comment, just something that shows all possible keys.

Do I have to write my own `Serializer` or is there something built-in? I use the `derive` annotation for my structs, but I don't know if that is relevant.

Comment: Non writing the line is how today you serialize a lack of value in TOML (somehow [relevant discussion](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/146)). It's easy.

Comment: Ok it seems null is not possible in toml. I want to write a configuration file and signal to the user that the key exists. Any suggestions? Writing a comment instead of a key value pair would be a great alternative but that would definitely require something custom.